# MVC.NET Model validation/inheritance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

So I have a view and a model to enter information for a person. Standard fields, name, lastname, etc. Now I need to add a new type of person, say Manager. For that person type, we need to collect new set of required fields, say "years of experience". Also, some labels for existing models should change dynamically for Manager (instead of Person Name should be Manager Name).
 I want to re-use existing Person model and view. Whats the best way to add new fields to existing model, but make them required ONLY when person type is Manager, as well as to change labels on some of the existing fields.
Currently required fields/labels are set up as attributes in Model statically.
So I seem to need a way to dynamically remove validation/.change labels. Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your validation is too complex for default validation with DataAnnotations. I'd recommend to use [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).

With that library you'll be able to keep all validations detached from your model. And you can use inheritance as well.

Also take a look at [this article](http://timgthomas.com/2013/09/simplify-client-side-validation-by-adding-a-server/).